# How to handle unexpected disconnect

Tags: c#, .net, .net-remoting

I've got a question concerning best practices with .NET remoting. The code is smelly and I need to do some refactoring.

The thing is: 
I've got multiple classes that derive from MarshalByRefObject and their data is used in the client software. 
Once the server disconnects I get RemotingException.

The bad thing about this is: My references to all the MarshalByRefObjects are all over the place (including but not limited to the GUI) and upon disconnection the exception turns up anywhere in my code.
Obviously I'd like to handle those exceptions in one place. Are there any best practices for this?

Essentially, I'd like to put together some sort of **"offline"**-mode for the **client**

Comment: Best practice would be to replace remoting with WCF (unless this is purely about inter-AppDomain remoting).

Comment: Can't you use global error handler (Application_Error in ASP.NET, Application.ThreadException event in winforms etc)?

Comment: the use of global error handlers is not suitable here, because I want to recover from such an event and when the global error handler gets called you're only seconds away from a shutdown - if I understand the concept.

Comment: @Richard: But there is no WCF replacement for marshal-by-ref.

Comment: @ulatekh Of course not. Changing from a "connected objects" (remoting) model to RPC (WCF) means significant changes, Primarily you would end up with a proxy on the client side – as per the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this problem with the use of Proxy Design Pattern